# Keyboard option shift:both_caps not taking effect on console

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, console, capslock

I am trying to get both shift keys pressed together to act as caps lock on the console in Xubuntu 18.04. On recent Debian/Ubuntus, /etc/default/keyboard can be used to configure the keyboard both for X and the console - this is what I have in it:

```
XKBMODEL=pc105
XKBLAYOUT=us
XKBVARIANT=dvorak
XKBOPTIONS=caps:swapescape,compose:menu,shift:both_capslock
```

To make settings from this file take effect, I run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and accept the options it reads from the file.

The first two options work as expected, while `shift:both_capslock` does not. I tried them in different combinations and individually.

Side note: in X, all three options work when applied with `setxkbmap`.

How can I make it work on the console?